# ¿Es posible modificar el tipo de campo de una tabla existente con datos en laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, float, integer, schema

Tengo una tabla donde estoy manejando números positivos, negativos y con decimales, pero olvide eso en el momento de crear el campo, el campo ahora es tipo `integer` y quiero pasarlo a `float`.

Mi tabla ejemplo:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('resultados', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('respuesta')->nullable();
    });
}
```

es posible cambiar el tipo de campo? como se puede hacer (en caso de ser posible).

> **aclarando que no estoy usando `modelos` por si eso es necesario. y estoy usando `MySQL`**

Comment: Que gestor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: @BetaM, Mysql, verdad olvide comentar eso, ya lo agrego.

Comment: Un duda, deseas cambiar el campo sin perder los datos o, no importa los datos (por ahora). Porque puedes cambiar tu columna para float así: `$table->float('amount', 8, 2);` y si deseas que sea decimal `$table->decimal('amount', 8, 2);

Comment: @EdgarGc, si no importaran los datos, no preguntaría por este medio, ya lo hubiera cambiado e esa forma, pregunto mas para saber si es posible por que si en un futuro me pasa algo como eso, ya seria muy tarde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modificar las propiedades de una tabla usando doctrine/dbal

para modificar las propiedades de una tabla debemos instalar doctrine/dbal con el comando

composer require doctrine/dbal

[image: Documentacion de laravel Doctrine]

una vez instalado creamos la migración con el comando

php artisan make:migration change_datatype_to_users_table

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al cambiar el tipo de dato o a su vez si es un string cambiar a text o cambiar la cantidad de caracteres del string debes poner ->change() para hacer los cambios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo.
Resulta que ya habia encontrado la solución en otro lado y olvide que tenia esta pregunta sin resolver.
Pero igual por tu ayuda te la dejare como la solución por que es practicamente lo mismo, con la unica diferencia que no ocupe instalar nada.